# Moving label center to new spot when orientation is changed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, orientation

I have tried this :

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
- (void)adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    intervalLabel.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
}
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        intervalLabel.center = CGPointMake(200, 200);

    }
}
```

But it didn't work. however, if I do this it will move it

```
- (IBAction)sup:(id)sender {
    intervalLabel.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
}
```

---

BTW The label is made in storyboard and is outleted to my view did load and set to (weak, nonatomic) and the button is also made in storyboards and is just a standard IBAction

Comment: Not clear on what you're trying to do - you're setting the center to 0,0 and then immediately calling moveLabel which sets it to 100,100. And you're only calling this on the landscape orientations and not calling anything on the portrait orientations. So there's no way this label should move

Comment: k i changed it so it should be right, but still the label doesnt move when the device is rotated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is you're not calling:

```
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
```

However, I'm guessing the real problem is that you're using autolayout (either intentionally or otherwise) and then trying to muck with the center which doesn't really work.

So my suggestion - either disable autolayout if you prefer to use the "old method" of setting frame and center (click on your UIViewController in the visual designer and uncheck "Use Autolayout") OR do what you're attempting using autolayout (meaning add/change constraints at rotation time).

After unchecking "Use Autolayout" for my UIViewController in the storyboard editor, the following worked for me:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        _intervalLabel.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    } else {
        _intervalLabel.center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    }    
}
```

That being said using Autolayout would be my recommendation.

Comment: Thankyou, that was exactly it, although is there a way to do it in storyboards?

Comment: Sure. Just make some constraints for your label in the storyboard editor and connect them to outlets in your viewcontroller. Then modify the constraints on rotation (by e.g. setting their 'constant' property.)